# Is it possible to invoke grep with a stored regular expression from a file?

Tags: regex, grep

I'm working on a nice long regular expression (for fun, yeah I know...) and I'd like to write it in a file so I can keep a better record of it.  Can I call grep like this:

```
grep regex.txt fileToSearch.txt
```

I've tried it and it doesn't work. Are there any flags I have to use or is this approach not possible?

Comment: why don't you use a shellscript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from `man grep`:

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)
```

Example:

```
$> cat ./file.txt 
.*a

$> echo "abcabc" | grep -o -P -f ./file.txt 
abca
```

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
grep "$(cat regex.txt)" fileToSearch.txt
```

or

```
grep --file=regex.txt fileToSearch.txt
```